# How can I vary the type parameter when dealing with a collection?

Tags: scala

Say I have a case class that has a type parameter T:

```
case class ProdutOption[T](name: String, value:T)
```

And this case class is contained in another case class like:

```
case class Product[T](id: String, options: Set[ProductOption[T]])
```

What is the correct way to model this?
I want my `options` parameter to be able to have different types of T... I don't want all items in the set to be forced to a specific type.

Is this scenario possible to model using type parameters like this?

Comment: How do you even plan to use `Options` if you don't know which types they have?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I am reading values sent in a JSON post...

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

Everything depends on whether your set of possible option types is **closed** (i.e. known statically) or **open** (unknown until runtime) and how exactly do you want to process these options.

If you can enumerate all possible options, use an ADT (algebraic data type):

```scala
sealed trait ProductOption[+T] {
  def name: String
  def value: T
}
object ProjectOption {
  case class SomeNumericOption(value: Int) extends ProductOption[Int] {
    def name: String = "numeric"
  }
  case class SomeTextualOption(value: String) extends ProductOption[String] {
    def name: String = "textual"
  }
}

case class Product(id: String, option: Set[ProductOption[_]])
```

You can then process these options in a type-safe way using pattern matching.

If your option hierarchy is not known then you should introduce some method for processing this option into the base trait, which will no longer be `sealed`:

```scala
trait ProductOption {
  def name: String

  def processMe(): Whatever = ...
}

case class Product(id: String, option: Set[ProductOption])
```

What exactly would `processMe` do depends on your use case.

This is a classical example of so called *expression problem*.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear what exactly you're looking for, but it may be useful to consider covariance for `ProductOption`:

```scala
case class ProductOption[+T](name: String, value: T)
```

This says that if `S` is a supertype of `T`, `ProductOption[T]` is a subtype of `ProductOption[S]`.

Specifically this then means that a `Product[Any]` allows `options` to be any kind of `ProductOption`:

```scala
Product("my favorite product", Set(ProductOption[String]("color", "blue"), ProductOption[ShirtSize]("size", ShirtSize.TwoXL))  // type is Product[AnyRef]
```

Comment: This way these options remain practically untyped which is not cool.